# How synaptic "Add Downloaded Packages" Works?

Tags: package-management, synaptic, bug-reporting

I have downloaded deb packages.

When I use **synaptic- Add downloaded packages** It just download some packages but not add (install) my all packages (Even main package!).

[image]

**According to my assumption, This option should add my deb packages to `/var/cache/apt/archives`. Then prompts to download if any dependency-package missing. Then Installs packages.**

However I can installs packages by `dpkg -i *.deb`. *But it not check if any package missing and not prompt to auto download them*.

So, suggest **alternative GUI or CLI tool [if not available then appropriate commands]** for `dpkg -i *.deb` to get above mentioned work efficiently (**check+auto download+install**) or How to solve no-efficient working of **synaptic's Add downloaded packages**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it wrong way. The "Add downloaded packages" item serves another item, "Generate package download script".

### How does it work?

1. Select packages that you need to install/upgrade. For example, `monodevelop` and `wine`. Synaptic will select a lot of other packages.
2. Generate download script. Save it on removable media.
3. Bring the script to another computer (with rapid network) and execute the script. It will download needed packages.
4. Bring packages back to original computer and add downloaded packages through Synaptic.
5. PROFIT!!!

And to install some downloaded packages, the `gdebi` is appropriate. Simply type `gdebi *.deb` and it will download dependencies and install all the packages specified.

Comment: `gdebi *.deb` not working see my parallel question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/457480/how-to-use-gdebi-for-mutiple-packages-or-any-alternative

Answer (score 0):

dpkg does not download dependencies; it simply checks to see if the required packages are installed.  apt, aptitude, and synaptic download dependencies.

However, they download dependencies based on the information contained in the configured package repositories.  You can't feed apt or Synaptic a deb file and have it download the required dependencies.  You must try to install it yourself with dpkg, and then install any required dependencies yourself.

Comment: If I can't feed debs to synaptic, then what "Add Downloaded Packages" option stands for?

Comment: I don't know.  Maybe it dumps them in `/var/cache/apt/archives`, but that doesn't mean that Synaptic will then resolve their dependencies.  For that to happen, the package must be in a repository, not simply on your disk.